# Passing functions to classes

Tags: java, function

I have a java form implemented using swing on which I want to place a number of panels in which I can draw on using the graphics2D package.

To do this, I implement the panels using an extension of JPanel thus:

```
public class GraphicsPanel  extends JPanel
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);

        // Need to specify a function from the calling class here
        MethodFromCallingClass();
    }
}
```

In the calling class I have

```
public GraphicsPanel Graphics1= new GraphicsPanel() ;

public void Graphics1_Paint()
{
   // Code to draw stuff on the Graphics1 panel
}
```

So question is how do I pass the function (Graphics1_Paint) from the calling class to the GraphicsPanel class?

I've tried reading about interfaces and lambdas but so far they make no sense.

Can anyone enlighten me please.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to pass the calling class (or some other *interface*) to the constructor of your `GraphicsPanel` like

```
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {
    private CallingClass cc;
    public GraphicsPanel(CallingClass cc) {
        this.cc = cc;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);    
        cc.MethodFromCallingClass(); // <-- invoke a call-back.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want to define what is drawn outside of the custom `JPanel` class, where you can pass what you want drawn to the `JPanel` instance at anytime. This is possible.

First, define an interface that contains one method that draws with a `Graphics2D` instance:

```
public interface DrawGraphics()
{
    public void draw(Graphics2D g);
}
```

Next you'll want to extend your `GraphicsPanel` a bit to have the ability to change an underlying instance of `DrawGraphics`.

So your constructor should now be:

```
public GraphicsPanel(DrawGraphics graphicsToDraw) { ...
```

You should also have a set method for the `DrawGraphics` stored so you can change it at anytime:

```
public void setDrawGraphics(DrawGraphics newDrawGraphics) { ...
```

Make sure you add some synchronization somewhere here, or create all `DrawGraphics` on the EDT because the `paintComponents` method will execute on the EDT.

Next the `paintComponents` method can simply draw the graphics:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)   
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g2d);

    // Need to specify a function from the calling class here
    graphicsToDraw(g2d);
}
```

And when you need to change the `DrawGraphics`:

```
// Calling from the EDT
myGraphicsPanel.setDrawGraphics(g -> g.drawString("Hello World!", 50, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the problem, but I'd like comments on usability and good practice

```
 public class CallingClass
  {
   public JPanel Graphics1 ;

   public CallingClass()
    {

       Graphics1 = new Graphics1_Paint();
    }

  public class Graphics1_Paint extends JPanel
   {
    public Graphics2D g2d;

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
        g2d.drawString("From Calling Class",10,10);
    }

  }

public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CallingClass();}
    });
}
```

Seems I don't need my GraphicsPanel class after all.

Comment: This is the common way of drawing custom graphics (by creating your own `JComponent`). It however doesn't do what you asked how to do in your question. In addition, you would probably want to keep the first line of paintComponent to call super for consistency. At that point there is no need to cast g as a (Graphics2D) into super.paintComponent.